# How to fine tune a pre-trained GAN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub

I would like to fine tune a pre-trained GAN available online using my own images. For example, BigGAN, which was trained on ImageNet, can generate realistic images. However, I do not want to generate the classes of images in ImageNet. I want to generate artificial images of my own image sets. How can I fine tune the pre-train models? Is it the same as fine-tuning other neural networks like a CNN image classification model? Is just replacing/retrain the last few layers is enough? It would be nice if I have see some examples in code of Tensorflow/Keras. Thanks so much!

BigGAN
https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-deep-256/1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question as defined in the [help]. If you want to find a more appropriate site for this question, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do it is by:

1. freezing the lower layers of the discriminator,
2. changing the embeddings.

References:

1. Mo S, Cho M, Shin J. Freeze the discriminator: a simple baseline for fine-tuning gans. arXiv preprint arXiv:2002.10964. 2020 Feb 25. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10964.pdf
   Code: https://github.com/sangwoomo/FreezeD
2. Li Q, Mai L, Alcorn MA, Nguyen A. A cost-effective method for improving and re-purposing large, pre-trained GANs by fine-tuning their class-embeddings. InProceedings of the Asian Conference on Computer Vision 2020. https://anhnguyen.me/project/biggan-am/
   Code: https://github.com/qilimk/biggan-am